# Override and disable Django admin CSS .dashboard .module table tr

Tags: django, django-admin, css-tables, css

I have some custom fields/modules in my Django admin template "app_index.html". Looking like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Element 1</th>
    <th>Element 2</th>
</tr>
```

In firebug I can see that this field inherits from Django's base.css which says:

```
.dashboard .module table th{
    width:100%
}
```

I have by now understood that if a field inherits from width: 100%, then width:auto will not work.

In firebug, if I disable the width:100% property it works, but then other things in the admin interface is broken.

I have also tried defining my own .dashboard .module table th{width:auto} to override, but it does not work. Only if I in firebug *disable* it.

tl;dr: I want to *disable* CSS on elements, in django admin.

Comment: So, you want to apply `width: auto` to only certain `th` elements? Could you show some more of the surrounding HTML of that snippet you posted?

Comment: Could you just assign your own class or id?

Comment: This may be a good time to use !important, all though I'm sure I'll get verbally beaten for suggesting it.  `width:auto !important`

Answer (score 0):

Semi-solution I found:

Since I did not want the lines to break I added a

```
white-space: nowrap
```

on the th's.

I tried with !important, did not work. 
Assigning it's own ID did not work either.

Hmm, as with the Django admin customization remains hard. But thanks for comments!